# Is amortized time complexity analysis broken for immutable colections?

Tags: scala, queue, complexity-theory, immutability, amortized-analysis

**Update:** this question is how can we use amortized analysis for immutable collections? Scala's immutable queue is just an example. How this immutable queue is implemented is clearly visible from sources. And as it was pointed in answers Scala's sources does not mention amortized time for it al all. *But guides and internet podcasts do.* And as I saw C# has the similar immutable queue with similar statements about amortized time for it.

The amortized analysis was invented originally for mutable collections. How we can apply it to a Scala's mutable Queue is clear. But how can we apply it to this sequence of operations for example?

```
val q0 = collection.immutable.Queue[Int]()
val q1 = q0.enqueue(1)
val h1 = q1.head
val q2 = q1.enqueue(2)
val h2 = q2.head
val (d2, q3) = q2.dequeue()
val (d1, q4) = q3.dequeue()
```

We have different immutable queues in sequence `q0`-`q4`. May we consider them as one single queue or not? How can we use O(1) `enqueue` operations to amortize both heavy `head` and the first `dequeue`? What method of amortized analysis can we use for this sequence? I don't know. I can not find anything in textbooks.

**Final answer:**

(Thanks to all who answered my question!)

In short: **Yes, and no!**

"No" because a data structure may be used as *immutable* but not *persistent*. The data structure is *ephemeral* if making a change we forget (or destroy) all old versions of the data structure. Mutable data structures is an example. Dequeuing of immutable queue with two strict lists can be called "amortized O(1)" in such ephemeral contexts. But *full persistence* with forking of the immutable data structure history is desirable for many algorithms. For such algorithms the expensive O(N) operations of the immutable queue with two strict lists are **not** amortized O(1) operations. So the guide authors should add an asterisk and print by 6pt font in footnote: ** for specially selected sequences of operations.*

In answers I was given an excellent reference: [Amortization, Lazy Evaluation, and Persistence: Lists with Catenation via Lazy Linking](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.54.4293&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

> We first review the basic concepts of lazy evaluation, amortization, and persistence. We next discuss why the traditional approach to amortization breaks down in a persistent setting. Then we outline our approach to amortization, which can often avoid such problems through judicious use of lazy evaluation.

We can create fully persistent immutable queue with amortized O(1) operations. It must be specially designed and use lazy evaluation. Without such framework with lazy evaluation of the structure parts and memorization of results we can not apply amortized analysis to fully persistent immutable data structures. (Also it is possible to create a double-ended queue with all operations having worst-case constant time and without lazy evaluation but my question was about amortized analysis).

**Original question:**

According to an original definition the amortized time complexity is a worst case averaged over sequence complexity for allowed sequences of operations: "we average the running time per operation over a (worst-case) sequence of operations" https://courses.cs.duke.edu/fall11/cps234/reading/Tarjan85_AmortizedComplexity.pdf See textbooks also ("Introduction To Algorithms" by Cormen et al. for example)

Scala's Collection Library guide states two `collection.immutable.Queue` methods (`head` and `tail`) have amortized O(1) time complexity: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/performance-characteristics.html This table does not mention complexities of `enqueue` and `dequeue` operations but another unofficial guide states O(1) time complexity for enqueue and amortized O(1) time complexity for dequeue. https://www.waitingforcode.com/scala-collections/collections-complexity-scala-immutable-collections/read

But what that statements for the amortized time complexity really mean? Intuitively they allow us to make predictions for algorithms with the data structure used such as any allowed by the data structure itself sequence of N amortized O(1) operations have no worse than O(N) complexity for the sequence. Unfortunately this intuitive meaning is clearly broken for immutable collections. For example, next function does have time complexity O(n^2) for 2n amortized O(1) (according to the guides) operations:

```
def quadraticInTime(n: Int) = {
  var q = collection.immutable.Queue[Int]()
  for (i <- 1 to n) q = q.enqueue(i)
  List.fill(n)(q.head)
}

val tryIt = quadraticInTime(100000)
```

The second parameter of `List.fill` method is a by name parameter and is evaluated n times in sequence. We can also use `q.dequeue._1` instead of `q.head` of course with the same result.

Also we can read in "Programming in Scala" by M. Odersky et al.: "Assuming that head, tail, and enqueue operations appear with about the same frequency, the amortized complexity is hence constant for each operation. So functional queues are asymptotically just as efficient as mutable ones." This contradicts to the worst case amortized complexity property from textbooks and wrong for `quadraticInTime` method above.

*But if a data structure has O(1) time complexity of cloning we can break amortized time analysis assumptions for it just by executing N worst case "heavy" operations on N the data structure copies in sequence. And generality speaking any immutable collection have O(1) time complexity of cloning.*

**Question:** is there a good formal definition of amortized time complexity for operations on immutable structures? The definition clearly must farther limit allowed sequences of operations to be useful.

Comment: The paragraph from "Programming in Scala" you mention is not referring to the actual implementations of the Scala collections, but just to the example of functional queues implemented as an exercise of the respective chapter.

Comment: The actual implementation adds an optimization to make `head` O(1) after a first `dequeue`. The 'head' in the lib is O(N) still before the first `dequeue`. That's why my question is what formal definition of "amortized O(1)" we use for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris Okasaki described how to solve this problem with lazy evaluation in [Amortization, Lazy Evaluation, and Persistence:
Lists with Catenation via Lazy Linking](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.54.4293&rep=rep1&type=pdf) from 1995. The main idea is that you can guarantee that some action is done only once by hiding it in a thunk and letting the language runtime manage evaluating it exactly once.

Comment: Excellent reference! A can not vote for you answer but thanks a lot! Lazy evaluation is inevitable in such framework, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think I understand you inevitability question.

Comment: I mean we can not create such amortized immutable structures without lazy evaluation. Lazy evaluation is not for free too, it can block other threads for example.

Comment: Yes, I don't know of another way to do it without lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for `Queue`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Queue.html) give tighter conditions for which the asymptotic complexity holds:

> Adding items to the queue always has cost O(1). Removing items has cost O(1), except in the case where a pivot is required, in which case, a cost of O(n) is incurred, where n is the number of elements in the queue. When this happens, n remove operations with O(1) cost are guaranteed. Removing an item is on average O(1).

Note that removing from an immutable queue implies that when `dequeue`ing, subsequent operations are on the returned `Queue`.  Not doing this also means that it's not actually being used as a queue:

```scala
val q = Queue.empty[Int].enqueue(0).enqueue(1)
q.dequeue()._1    // 1
q.dequeue()._1    // 1
```

In your code, you're not actually using the `Queue` as a queue.  Addressing this:

```scala
def f(n: Int): Unit = {
  var q = Queue.empty[Int]
  (1 to n).foreach { i => q = q.enqueue(i) }
  List.fill(n) {
    val (head, nextQ) = q.dequeue
    q = nextQ
    head
  }
}

def time(block: => Unit): Unit = {
  val startNanos = System.nanoTime()
  block
  println(s"Block took ${ System.nanoTime() - startNanos }ns")
}
```

```
scala> time(f(10000))
Block took 2483235ns

scala> time(f(20000))
Block took 5039420ns
```

Note also the if we do an approximately equal number of `enqueue` and `head` operations on the same `scala.collection.immutable.Queue`, the `head` operations are in fact constant time even without amortization:

```scala
val q = Queue.empty[Int]
(1 to n).foreach { i => q.enqueue(i) }
List.fill(n)(Try(q.head))
```

Comment: My example is oversimplified purposely to illustrate that quadratic behavior is possible with immutable queues even for code looking innocent. It is not a real code. But it is possible to imagine a real code checking a queue head while enqueuing new items once for each new item added or some algorithm on graphs with immutable queues filled along paths.  

Of course q.head has a constant time for empty queue. :) But my quadratic  example has _exactly_ equal number of enqueue and head operations too. And it is _allowed_ sequence of operations with immutable queues.

Comment: Your example does not in fact have an equal number of enqueued and head operations on _any_ queue if _n_ is greater than 1.

Comment: I just have added two counters and tested that `quadraticInTime` function executes equal numbers of `enqueue` and `head` method calls for each n from 0 to 1000. Of course each `enqueue` call creates new immutable queue object, If we speak about amortized complexity with immutable data structures we have no choice but to count all operations and time for all such updated data structure states in the sequence in total.

Comment: For _n_ = 2, there are three queues.  Two of them have 1 enqueue operation and 0 head operations.  The third has 0 enqueue operations and 2 head operations.  1 is not equal to 0 nor is 2.

Comment: In this case we could not count a sequence of `enqueue` operations to amortize a single pivoting `dequeue`. To amortize it we have to count all `enqueue` operations in sequence as operations over a single abstract queue while the Queue object pointers returned are different for each item enqueued. But there is no difference for analysis between single `dequeue` and `head`. Finally while doing amortizing analysis we are looking for worst case sequence of _operations_. Specific object interfaces are irrelevant for it.